# Does post_save hook runs immediately after creating model in Django?

Tags: python, django, security

I have `post_save` method which needs `pk`.

```
def create_key(instance=None, sender=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
      last_index = instance.pk
      instance.private_key = cipher(last_index).encrypt(instance.private_key)
      instance.save()
```

Before calling it I assign `self.private_key` not encrypted `private_key`.

**Question**: Can attacker get not encrypted `private_key` from DB in time period between `save` method and `post_save`?

Comment: Why are you not doing this in `pre_save`?

Comment: @OzgurVatansever I corrected it, I need `instance.pk`

Comment: My guess is yes, but you could probably test this by putting a break point in your post_save function and manually query your db. Though, it might be safer to allow the field to be blank or null instead and update it after you save.

Comment: @KeiferSebastian yeah, I will try it. Tricky moment: I need `private_key` for `post_save`. I mean: while creating i generate `private_key` and should send it to `post_save`

Comment: If you can lock the table and are using an auto incrementing pk you could find out the next pk before saving.